# Para que serve e qual a aplicação do serviço Athena da AWS?

Tags: amazon-aws

Lendo a [documentação do AWS Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/athena/) - percebe-se que esse serviço oferece uma maneira de fazer queries em arquivos estocados no S3 através de SQL tradicionais e sem passar por um ETL. Essa é a idéia básica.

Mas eu não sei exatamente qual a motivação para se usar esse serviço. 
Seria uma espécie de Elastic service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, seria mais como uma *external table* em um Hive ou Oracle, por exemplo.

Você utiliza o Glue Crawler para fazer o *infer schema* e armazenar o metadado.
A partir daí, só fazer `select * from sua_tabela;`.